# Невозможно подключиться к iCloud с iOS 7(Iphone 4)

Tags: ios

Мой iPhone 4 под управлением iOS 7.1.2 не подключается к iCloud.  Имя учетной записи и пароль верны, но ничего не синхронизируется.

Если я повторно ввожу пароль, iCloud переходит к процедуре двухфакторной проверки, выдавая мне 6-значные номера на Android телефон, но не давая мне нигде на iPhone ввести их - меня просто просят ввести пароль iCloud на др. устройстве Apple, а затем 6-значный номер (что я не могу сделать, поскольку некуда вводить 6-значный номер), поэтому я снова ввожу пароль, что возвращает меня в тот же цикл с новым 6-значным номером.

Comment: Поддержка iPhone 4 и iOS 7 прекратилась ещё девять лет назад, так что ничего удивительного, наверное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно посмотреть системные требования [тут](https://support.apple.com/ru-ru/HT204230#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20iCloud%20Drive%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0,%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D1%81%20%D0%9E%D0%A1%20Windows.)

Цитируя текст со страницы:

> Чтобы пользоваться iCloud, на iPhone 4, iPod touch (5-го поколения), iPad или iPad mini должна быть установлена iOS 9 или более поздней версии, а на компьютере Mac — OS X El Capitan 10.11 или более поздней версии.